# Any good tool that opens a .psd (photoshop) file which was repaired/corrupted

Tags: windows-xp, adobe-photoshop

I was working with a .psd Photoshop file and my system power suddenly went off. When I switched on my system, I clicked the .psd file and it said "couldn't open the file". Any good tool that opens a .psd which was repaired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/), maybe it uses another approach and/or is more tolerant to errors in the file.

There are two other repair services, [Advanced PSD Repair](http://www.datanumen.com/apsr/index.htm) and the [PSD Repair Tool](http://www.fileinternals.com/psd-repair-photoshop-recovery.htm), but I don't know how trustworthy those two are.

On the other hand, check the size of the file, if it is now smaller then it used to be, then there's nothing to rescue.